# Kate showing no language dictionary found

Tags: manjaro, konsole, kate

[image]

I'm getting these whenever I'm accessing kate in manjaro kde, how do I solve this. I'm using konsole, zsh if it does any help.

Comment: well, it seem some library is missing (I'd guess `aspell`). Are those just warnings. or you cannot run Kate at all?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your language-specific version of `hunspell` is missing (which in turn should install your missing libraries as requirements on its own).

In my case `sudo pacman -S hunspell-en_us` did the trick.
In your case it seems that you'll need an `en_in` version (which is not available in my repos, but that might be different on your system).